# Java 8 stream API: get first found collection element

Tags: java, java-stream

There is a class

```
public class Event {
    public boolean isActive() {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

There is a `TreeSet<Event> events` holding some thousands elements. I need to effectively find any active `Event` and get the element.

I want to use a `parallelStream` to take advantage of multi-threading.

Is it possible to do the same way as with `anyMatch()` only returning the found element?

```
boolean hasActiveEvent = events.parallelStream().anyMatch(event -> event.isActive());
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, using filter & find

```
Optional<Event> result = events
        .parallelStream()
        .filter(Event::isActive)
        .findAny();
```